# Entropy of Dirichlet distributed vector

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, inference, dirichlet-distribution

Suppose I have two Dirichlet distributed vectors $X$ and $Y$ such that $ X \sim \text{Dirichlet}(\alpha) $, $ Y \sim \text{Dirichlet}(\beta) $ with fixed vectors of hyperparameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I need to evaluate and compare the "spikiness" of resulting vectors. To this end, consider random variables $ A = X \log X $, $B = Y \log Y $ (entropies of corresponding variables). Now I need to statistically prove that one of the entropies is bigger than the other one.

**Disclaimer**: I don't have a lot of experience in statistical tests (and, equivalently, understanding of them). For this reason, the questions following may be misguided, and pointing out the ways to improve the questions themselves would be helpful.

I already know how to get the point estimates of $A$ and $B$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) -- this was pretty much everything I've found about these random variables. However, I understand that comparing point estimates is not enough for solid statistical conclusions. How do I get additional information on $A$ and $B$ (e.g., confidence intervals)?

After that, suppose I have two 95% confidence intervals $[A_l, A_r]$ and $[B_l, B_r]$. If $A_r < B_l$, can I state that $A < B$ with 95% confidence?

Comment: Do you know the parameters of the two Dirichlet distributions?

Comment: Yes, they're known beforehand. As in the question, "with *fixed* vectors"

Comment: Then why not calculate the entropy from the distributions directly rather than from samples from them?  No doubt I'm missing something...

Comment: @jbowman, in that case I will get *point estimate* of entropy. But since entropy of Dirichlet-distributed vector is a random variable by itself, we still have to introduce confidence intervals and all that stuff... right?